# How to use the 'any()' function to search for multiple substrings?

Tags: python

I have the following code where I am trying to open a textfile, read through it line by line, and if a line has a certain country code (`US`,`BR`), add it to a list `myNames`:

```
 f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    countries = ['US', 'BR']
    myNames = []
    for line in f:
        line = f.readline()
        if any(x in line for x in countries):
            myNames.append(line)
```

Unfortunately I think my use of `any()` must be incorrect because it is yielding only a small number from 1 country and none from the second even though I can verify that there are more of each type. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say without knowing what `x` is and what's in the file, but this snippet:

```
for line in f:
    line = f.readline()
```

is reading two lines at a time -- `for line in f` is already iterating over the file line by line, by reading twice you're skipping every other line. That would explain why you're getting too few results.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, I removed 'line = f.readline()' and it started working properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    if any(x in line for x in countries):
        myNames.append(line)
```

otherwise you will skip a good number of lines.